# Material-ui v4 shows component names in html DOM class attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

After migrating from material-ui v3 to v4, noticed the react component/function name in the class attribute inside the HTML.

Is that expected? Might this somehow affect overriding class properties already noticing issues when trying to override with new styles which do not apply.

Also is there a possibility to remove those?

The component names are: WrapperComponent, withRouter, CustomerDetailsContainer among others.

[image]

Comment: This is just in dev mode (to make it easier to tell what component the styles were generated for). In production mode these class names would just be `jssxxx`. This naming would not affect overriding class properties.

Comment: @RyanCogswell that was some helpful info especially regarding the overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material-UI uses [class name generator](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#class-names) to generate unique class names for styled components to enable style isolation. The classname prefix is different depending on the current environment.

- In non-production mode, the [displayed name](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/9bd4277ecd660ebe2fd4cb08960f58e98ddb6d43/packages/material-ui-styles/src/withStyles/withStyles.js#L33) of the component is used as classname prefix
- In production mode, by default `jss` is used as classname prefix

You can fake the environment by setting `process.env.NODE_ENV` at the beginning of the program to see the change in classname prefix

```
// change to "production" to see the different in classname prefix
process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";

class App extends React.Component {
  static displayName = "MyFabulousApp";

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return <div className={classes.root}>Hello world</div>;
  }
}

const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "grey"
  }
};

const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);
const MyApp = withStyles(styles)(AppWithRouter);

console.log(AppWithRouter.displayName); // withRouter(MyFabulousApp)-root-1
```

Generated class name of the element in development

```
withRouter(MyFabulousApp)-root-1
```

In production

```
jss1
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI - Classname Prefix]