# Material UI - random numbers appended to MUI attributes

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use Material UI elements.

When I try to use the table, random margins/width attributes (that I cannot find the source of are being forced to narrow the cell width inside rows.

When I inspect the css, I can see that Material UI attributes are appended with random numbers that I then need to use to write css overrides in my own styles file.

What creates the random numbers?

Does anyone know which property is imposing a narrow width of the cell inside the row and how to switch it off? [image]

Comment: Those random numbers are created by class name generator. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63849978/9449426) answer.

Comment: What version of Material-UI are you using?