# How to override border-color in outlined styled TextField component in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

The task is to use Material UI outlined input field (`TextField` component from `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",`) and style it with custom blue colour.

Here's what I managed to achieve:
[image: Desired input field in active state]

Current theme override for InputLabel:

```
import { createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export const muiTheme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      outlined: {
        "&$focused": {
          color: "#3f3fa0",
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

The above general theme override helps change the label ("Email address") colour to blue.
The blue `border-color` is achieved by wrapping `TextField` in a styled component with the below CSS:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

export const CustomTextField = styled(TextField)`
  .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: #3f3fa0;
  }
`;
```

I render the above component like this (inside of `ThemeProvider`):

```
<CustomTextField
  variant="outlined"
  label={label}
/>
```

This hacky solution works, as seen on the image I supplied above, however, sometimes Mui code decides to append [random numbers to their class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843252/material-ui-v4-shows-component-names-in-html-dom-class-attributes/63849978#63849978) and this causes my custom (hacky) CSS solution to fail and it ends up looking like this:

[image: TextField with random CSS classess]

I tried to add almost any combination I could think of to the Mui overrides object to override the `border-color` property but could not figure it out. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to override border-color on OutlinedInput (material-ui v4).

I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-curran-99s0i?file=/src/App.js) here

```
const defaultColor = "#ff0000";
const hoverColor = "#0000ff";
const focusColor = "#00ff00";

const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        // Hover state
        "&:hover $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: hoverColor
        },
        // Focused state
        "&$focused $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: focusColor
        }
      },
      // Default State
      notchedOutline: {
        borderColor: defaultColor
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think I've never used `$` before `notchedOutline`, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not that experienced with `material-ui` but this seems to be something you are looking for.
https://mui.com/styles/api/#examples

Using that, I think it is possible to customize `classname`.